# How to find (* comments *) using Java's regexp?

Tags: java, regex, pascal

I don't know how to work with '(', ')', and '*' that can be in comment. Comments are multiline.

Comment: If this `(* comment *)` is a comment then regex cannot really handle `(* zz (* zz *)` or `(* zz *) zz *)`

Comment: It's not clear to me, whether the question is simply about masking the parenthesis and the asterisk, or about context-recognition (Strings in comments, comments in strings, nested comments and so on).

Comment: @user unknown - I know how to escape parentesis and asterisk, this question ia about how to handle nested,containing * and ( or ) comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple pattern to handle that is:

```
\(\*(.*?)\*\)
```

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/afqLCDssIx

You probably also want to set the single-line flag, `(?s)\(\*(.*?)\*\)`

Note that is doesn't handle cases like `(*` in strings, or other weird combination. Your best bet is to use a parser, for example [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org), which alread has a ready [Pascal grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list) ([direct link](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1279217060704/pascal3.zip)).

Comment: +1 for finding an actual grammar that includes this. Just for completeness: even with a parser generator, dealing with potentially nested comments can be tricky. Also, you need to have the grammar for the rest of the (non-comment) content. E.g. if I have no knowledge of the rest of the syntax, then just looking for an opening `(*` token may cause me to find something inside a string literal.

Comment: @phooji - Thanks! A parser should handle even nested constructs - it does so easily enough for the whole code structure. That said, I doubt `(* zz *) zz *)` is valid - very few languages actually allow nested comments. `/* 1 /* 2 */ 1 */` wouldn't pass in any C++ compiler `:)`

Comment: I want to underline, that you have to mask `\(\*(.*?)\*\)` the backslashes in java which looks like this `String r = "\\(\\*(.*?)\\*\\)";` in Javacode.

Comment: @Kobi: Right. I guess I'm thinking of a more old school Lex/Yacc setup where, to parse comments, you put the lexer in a special 'comment' mode.

Comment: Actually, I took part in a programming competition, I spent a lot of time on first tasks, but there was another one: "Delete all {}, // and (* *) comments from input Pascal code". I had only 4 minutes to do it, so I decided to use Java's regular expressions. I managed to remove // and {} comments, but my third regexp didn't work well. So, as I understand now, that task should be done wuthout using regexps. But with your regexp my program, maybe, could succeed most of tests, however, so thanks for help!

Comment: This regex does not work with nested comments. Not innermost comments. Not outermost comments.

Comment: @ridgerunner - The question doesn't ask for nested comments. Nested comments are not common, and not valid in most languages. It seems in Pascal it depends on the version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842443/comments-in-pascal

Answer (score 4):

If you want to find the most inner nested comment for /* */ example

```
/* 
/*
comment1
/*
comment2
*/
*/
*/
```

regular expression will be

```
\/\*[^/*]*(?:(?!\/\*|\*\/)[/*][^/*]*)*\*\/
```

this will find

```
/*
comment2
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the handling of nested comments, although it is true that you cannot use a Java regex to match an *outermost* comment, you *can* craft one which will match an *innermost* comment (with some notable exceptions - see caveats below). (Note that the: `\(\*(.*?)\*\)` expression will NOT work in this case as it does not correctly match an innermost comment.) The following is a tested java program which uses a (heavily commented) regex which matches only innermost comments, and applies this in an iterative manner to correctly strip nested comments:

```java
public class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String subjectString = "out1 (* c1 *) out2 (* c2 (* c3 *) c2 *) out3";
        String regex = "" +
            "# Match an innermost pascal '(*...*)' style comment.\n" +
            "\\(\\*      # Comment opening literal delimiter.\n" +
            "[^(*]*      # {normal*} Zero or more non'(', non-'*'.\n" +
            "(?:         # Begin {(special normal*)*} construct.\n" +
            "  (?!       # If we are not at the start of either...\n" +
            "    \\(\\*  # a nested comment\n" +
            "  | \\*\\)  # or the end of this comment,\n" +
            "  ) [(*]    # then ok to match a '(' or '*'.\n" +
            "  [^(*]*    # more {normal*}.\n" +
            ")*          # end {(special normal*)*} construct.\n" +
            "\\*\\)      # Comment closing literal delimiter.";
        String resultString = null;
        java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(
                    regex,
                    java.util.regex.Pattern.COMMENTS);
        java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(subjectString);
        while (m.find())
        { // Iterate until there are no more "(* comments *)".
            resultString = m.replaceAll("");
            m = p.matcher(resultString);
        }
        System.out.println(resultString);
    }
}
```

Here is the short version of the regex (in native regex format):

```
\(\*[^(*]*(?:(?!\(\*|\*\))[(*][^(*]*)*\*\)
```

Note that this regex implements Jeffrey Friedl's *"Unrolling-the-loop"* efficient technique and is quite fast. (See: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124)).

**Caveats:** This will certainly NOT work correctly if any comment delimiter (i.e. `(*` or `*)`) appears within a string literal and thus, should NOT be used for general parsing. But a regex like this one is handy to use from time to time - for quick and dirty searching within an editor for example.

See also my answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358058/regex-for-nested-values/5360139#5360139) for someone wanting to handle nested C-style comments.